# Computing expectation of conditional characteristic function of the Heston model and variance process $V_t$

Tags: stochastic-processes, heston, characteristic-function

I'm using the following Heston model:

\begin{align}
\text{d}X_t &= -\dfrac{1}{2}  V_t \text{d}t +\sqrt{V_t} \text{d}B_t, \\
\text{d}V_t &= -\lambda(V_t-\kappa) \text{d}t + \sigma \sqrt{V_t} \text{d}W_t.
\end{align}

The conditional moment generating function of this model is

\begin{align}
\varphi_t(u,w) =& \mathbb{E}[\exp(uX_T+wV_T)\vert \mathcal{F}_t] \notag \\
 =& \exp(\phi_{T-t}(u,w)+V_t\psi_{T-t}(u,w)+uX_t), \text{ } (u,w) \in \mathbb{R}^2,
\end{align}

I already know the unconditonal expectation

\begin{equation*}
\mathbb{E}[\exp(uX_t+wV_t)V_t] = \left[\partial_w \phi_t(u,w) + V_0 \partial_w \psi_t(u,w)\right] e^{X_0u} \phi_t(u,w) \exp(\phi_t(u,w) + V_0\psi_t(u,w)+iuX_0).
\end{equation*}

For my applications I want to compute for the price process $S_t = \exp(X_t)$ and strike $K$ the expectation

\begin{equation*}
\mathbb{E}\left[\exp\left(\phi_{T-t}(\frac{k\pi}{b-a},0)+V_t\psi_{T-t}(\frac{k\pi}{b-a},0) + \frac{ik\pi}{b-a} (\log(S_t /K)-a) \right) V_t\right]
\end{equation*}

for $a<0$ and $b>0$ and $k$ as integer. My approach was to insert $\exp(X_t)$ for $S_t$ and use the logarithm rules, but than I was stuck. I would be thankful, if you can help me to compute this expectation.

Comment: Two comments: 1) you talk about the MGF, but you have the complex number $i$ in your formulas - is that a typo? 2) if you want to compute an expectation of the form $E(e^{\alpha x + \beta y}(Ax + B y))$, you need to augment the transforms, see equations 2.13-2.16 in the original DPS paper http://pages.stern.nyu.edu/~dbackus/Disasters/DuffiePanSingleton%20jumps%20Econometrica%2000.PDF. Did that help?

Comment: Yes you are right in 1), sorry for that. Thank you for your hint, I will give it a try.

Comment: Let me know if you got stuck